# Knowing what to test in android

Tags: android, unit-testing

I've been starting to read up on android testing: https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-unit-testing.html

I'm confused what should be tested in an app.  Obviously simple, non-android specific methods like one that would sort a list of full names by last name should be unit tested.

But what if I had a method that iterated through a layout to determine the child view that was selected, is that suitable for unit testing with a sample input layout, or does this fall under functional/ui testing?  The method looks like this:

```
public void setSelectedPerson(ViewGroup vg, View selected) {
    for(int i=0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        if(v == selected) {
            selectedPerson = (Person)v.getTag();
        }
    }
}
```

I could test this through a UI test that clicked on part of the app and verified the result.  But is that overkill?  Would a more appropriate test be a unit test to create a very basic viewgroup with 2 children, assign one of them to "selected", and finally make sure the selected Persons object match?

Comment: You might be interested in the Roboletric project for unit-testing activities. Maybe you'll find it natural enough to not have to worry about overkilling.

Comment: It really depends on what kind of testing you're looking for. From a unit/behaviour driven approach, you want to mock the button, invoke this method and then validate that the selectedPerson matches what you expect. From an instrumentation perspective, you want to validate that pressing a button has the result you expect on screen.